# Force widget resizing in Qt

Tags: qt, resize, widget

I'm writing an image viewer, and I'd like some behavior from Qt:

imagine the viewer displays the image in a 256x256 box. Now I want that ctrl+Z do a zoom + resizing of the window; ie. show the 2x zoomed image in a 512x512 box, how can I do that?

Also, imagine know the user gave a certain shape to my viewer, and that he presses F10, I want to change the layout to display the viewer in the same size (if possible, eg not overflowing the screen) and add additional controls under it, and resize the complete widget in a way that the viewer widget does

Comment: what the problem to use resize() function of QWidget ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [QWidget::minimumSize](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) property to change the widget minimal size.

If the size of your zoomed image gets bigger than the screen, you might have to put your widget into a [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qscrollarea.html#details).

Comment: But wouldn't this forbid the user to then resize the widget?